# Twig Template on Symfony Exception Page not rendering head

Tags: symfony, twig

I've some trouble with Twig template.

I've overload the TwigBundle by copy it on app/TwigBundle/.
Now I want custom my 404 page for exemple. I don't know why, but I've all HTML code from the view, good layout, but the head of the main layout is empty, so this doesn't load any CSS file or JS!.

In all other page, all work find, this problem appear only from exception view!

My architecture:

error404.html.twig    (extends)-> layout-public-user.html.twig  (overload content block)-> layout.html.twig  (include)->  head.html.twig

**View 404:**

```
{# 
APP > TwigBundle > Exceptions > error404.html
#}

{% extends "::layout-public-v2.html.twig" %}

{% block title %}Erreur 404 (page non trouvée) - {{ parent() }}{% endblock %}
//blablablabla
```

**Layout-public:**

```
{# 
APP > layout-public-v2.html
variables : view_content
#}

{% block topBar %}
{% include '::topbar/topbar-public-v2.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}

<section id="content">
{% block body %}

 {{ view_content|raw }}
{% endblock %}
</section>
```

**Layout:**

```
{# 
    APP > layout.html
#}

{% include '::header/header-v2.html.twig' %}

<body class="">
{% block topBar %}
{% endblock %}

{% if app.user %}
    {% include '::layout-user-v2.html.twig' with {'view_content': block('content')} %}
{% else %}
    {% include '::layout-public-v2.html.twig' with {'view_content': block('content')} %}
{% endif %}

{% include '::footer/footer-js-v2.html.twig' %}

</body>
```

**header:**

```
{# 
  APP > header/header-v2.html
#}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" class="app">
<head>
  {% block head %}
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JobaPic</title>
    <meta name="description" content="app, web app, responsive, admin dashboard, admin, flat, flat ui, ui kit, off screen nav" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" /> 
    {% include '::header/header-css-v2.html.twig' %}
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="{{ asset('bundles/general/js/ie/html5shiv.js') }}"></script>
      <script src="{{ asset('bundles/general/js/ie/respond.min.js') }}"></script>
      <script src="{{ asset('bundles/general/js/ie/excanvas.js') }}"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  {% endblock %}
</head>
```

**header-css**

```
{# 
  APP > header/header-css-v2.html
#}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/general/css/bootstrap.css') }}" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/general/css/animate.css') }}" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/general/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/general/css/font.css') }}" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/general/js/calendar/bootstrap_calendar.css') }}") type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/general/css/app.css') }}" type="text/css" />
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the twig source (at leas for the assets you may used)? What's the exact path you created the exception twig files?

Comment: I've edited and give you twig template source. the exact path for my 404 page is : app/Ressources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig

Comment: If you get a view source of the output, do you see the included header css/js? If yes, check the path if they are correct. As you know the path of extended or included file (e.g. `::blahblah.html.twig`) should be *app/Resources/views/blahblah.html.twig*

Comment: No, went I inspect DOM with chrome toolbar, the tag <head></head> is empty...

Comment: I think you should first extend the layout.html which include the public-layout.html inside; but you said first you extend public-layout.html. The issue seems to be the way you extend because it seems the `{% block topbar %}` get overlaoded by the empty block

Comment: OMG you have totally right! Thanks a lot this work now. Post last comment in an answer for I can up and validate!

Comment: Good, happy to hear it; done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should first extend the `layout.html` which include the `public-layout.html` inside; but you are extending `public-layout.html` first.
The issue seems to be the way you extend because it seems the {% block topbar %} get overlaoded by the empty block